# Is it possible to have a sine series with $b_1 \sin(x/2) + b_2 \sin(3x/2) + \cdots$ instead of $b_1 \sin(x) + b_2 \sin(2x) + \cdots$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

If we have an odd function $f(x)$ defined on $(-\pi, \pi)$, we have a sine series for it $$f(x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \sin(kx),$$ with $$b_k = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(kx)\,dx.$$ Is it possible to have a sine series for the same function $f(x)$ of the form $$f(x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k \sin\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}x\right)?$$

Comment: Just set $x\mapsto x/2$ and let $b_{2n}=0$ in the regular sine series.

Comment: Makes sense. So now: is it always possible to have a sine series for an odd function on $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$ of the form $c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \sin(3x) + c_3 \sin(5x) + \cdots$? Do we actually need all the sine terms?

Comment: Yes, the terms are orthogonal to each other. In particular, the closure of the span of a subset of them doesn't contain the rest. $\sin(2x)$ wouldn't be approximated by those series.

Comment: @Hellen: That also makes sense. Is there a way to look at an arbitrary function and know if it can be approximated by those series or not?

Comment: @alpha I believe the equivalent condition is that $g(x) = g(\pi-x)$ for $x \in (0, \pi)$ and $g(x) = g(-\pi-x)$ for $x \in (-\pi, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g : \left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ be defined as $g(x) = f(2x)$. No expand it to $(-\pi, \pi)$ such that $g(x) = g(\pi-x)$ for $x > 0$ and $g(x) = g(-\pi-x)$ for $x < 0$. These conditions guarantee that in the expansion

$$g(x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k \sin(kx)$$

the even terms are zero, i.e.

$$f(2x) \sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{2k+1} \sin( (2k+1) x )$$

so

$$f(x) \sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{2k+1} \sin \left( \frac{2k+1}{2} \cdot x \right).$$